# Rational trigonometric identities with real parameters

Tags: trigonometry

I did a lot of reading and thinking about trigonometric identities with parameters in the last couple of days, but didn't manage to come up with a solution to my specific problem. In general terms, most identities have a $1$ or maybe a $2$ or some integers in them, mainly because of the Pythagorean identity $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$, or half-angle formulas etc. I am wondering if it is possible to extend trigonometric identities such that general real parameters can also be included? I'm curious about this in general, but specifically, I am wondering about the identity

$$\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}=\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos x},$$

which can be proven straightforwardly

$$\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}=\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}\frac{1-\sin x}{1-\sin x}=\frac{\cos x (1-\sin x)}{1-\sin^2 x}=\frac{\cos x (1-\sin x)}{\cos^2 x}=\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos x}.$$

Can this identity somehow be extended to $\frac{\cos x}{a\sin x+b}$ such that there are no additive constants left in the denominator? In this case, following the above scheme, we can manipulate the LHS

$\frac{\cos x}{a\sin x+b}=\frac{\cos x}{a\sin x+b}\frac{a\sin x-b}{a\sin x-b}=\frac{\cos x (a\sin x-b)}{a^2-b^2\sin^2 x}$, but we have the additive constant $a^2$ left in the denominator, and I am not aware of a way how to get rid of it. My goal is to represent $\frac{\cos x}{a\sin x+b}$ or $\frac{1}{a\sin x+b}$ as a sum of (powers of) the usual trigonometric functions $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\sec x$ and $\csc x$; products like $\sin x \cos x$ are also fine, but again, additive constants in the denominator are an issue.

I guess either this is extremely straightforward and so easy that I don't see the solution, or it's extremely hard. Any insight on the general case, or even better on the specific case is greatly appreciated. Happy holidays!

Comment: The quotient $$\frac{1}{a\sin x + b}$$ can be expressed as the series $$\frac1b\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{-a \sin x}{b}\right)^k},$$ only provided that $|a\sin x|<|b|.$

Comment: Yes, thank you, I am aware of that. But it would be great to have an easier representation with only a few terms, not an infinite number of summands